# How do I properly bind an ASCII string in the form of a list<byte> to a textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a List that represents an ASCII string, and I'm trying to let it be edited via a textbox. I've set up the binding like this:

```
public List<byte> ParamData;

var b = new TextBox();
b.DataContext = ParamData;
var binding = new Binding(".");
binding.Converter = new ListToStringConverter();
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
b.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);


internal class ListToStringConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var orig = (List<byte>) value;
        var res = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(orig.ToArray());
        return res;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var orig = (string) value;
        var res = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(orig);
        return new List<byte>(res);
    }
}
```

However, I find that changing the text in the textbos doesn't trigger ConvertBack, and ParamData doesn't actually get updated. I've tried triggering UpdateSource() on text change in the textbox, nbut itl still nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think, You should change the property "public List<byte> ParamData;" to a DependencyProperty. A `List<>` doesnt have any notify events for using it with binding.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I don't understand, can you give me an example of how that would work? I can bind individual elements of the list to a textbox fine, I just need to be able to do it for the whole list.

Comment: Not the best example, but might give you a direction: _(it's C#)_ http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/BindingDependencyPropertytoTextBlock.htm

Comment: You can bind only to properties not to fields, so change to `public List<byte> ParamData { get; set; }`. And it should probably (not sure what your DataContext is) be `new Binding("ParamData")`.

Comment: Why a List, when you're shoehorning via an array all the time? Why not just use an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set binding source to a property, which can be updated by binding. as of now, binding uses entire object as its source and cannot replace it with completely different object (new list from ConvertBack method)

```
public class ByteListWrapper
{
    public List<byte> ParamData { get; set; }
}

var b = new TextBox();
b.DataContext = new ByteListWrapper { ParamData = someData };
var binding = new Binding("ParamData")
{
    Converter = new ListToStringConverter(),
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
};

b.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

so again: now binding updates value of a source property, instead of replacing source (which it cannot do)

Comment: `cannot replace it with completely diferent object (new list from ConvertBack method)` thanks, this is what I was missing